# Transposing an excel spreadsheet with a headings of dates and columns with names, time ins and outs for time sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a time sheet with the headers being Employee Name, Time in/out, and a range of dates.

It looks like this replicated to a larger volume.

[image]

However, the desired format to 'transpose' this into is:

[image]

We also receive a large volume of such spreadsheets so manual transposition is not desired.

Comment: To help us help you please add your sample data _as text_, so we can copy/paste it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what it seems, the easiest way to do this manually would be to select the entire table, copy. Then right-click in a different area and choose Paste Special.... Select the Transpose checkbox and OK.

If you want to automate this, you can record a macro that performs the steps. Beware of how you select your data so when you run the macro again it will select all the data instead of a rectangle with the same dimensions as when you recorded the macro.

Comment: Hello good folks, my apologies. This is the first time posting to Stack Overflow. I edited the first image.

Answer (score 0):

TRhe general idea is to loop over the source data, identifying Names, Date and Time.  Then build a build a new table in the required layout.

Doing this with Variant Arrays will make it quite fast.

Something like this

```
Sub TransposeTime(wsSrc As Worksheet, Optional wsDst As Worksheet)
    Dim rSrc As Range, rDst As Range
    Dim Src As Variant, Dst As Variant
    Dim EmployeeCount As Long
    Dim DateCount As Long
    Dim SrcRow As Long, DstRow As Long, DateRow As Long

    On Error GoTo EH

    If wsSrc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Get reference to source data.  Use Column B to get number of rows
    With wsSrc
        Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With

    ' Put source data in a Variant Array
    Src = rSrc.Value2

    ' Count Employees and Dates
    EmployeeCount = Application.CountA(rSrc.Columns(1)) - 1
    DateCount = Application.CountA(rSrc.Rows(1)) - 2

    ' if wsDst is missing, overwrite source
    If wsDst Is Nothing Then
        Set wsDst = wsSrc
        wsSrc.UsedRange.Clear
    End If

    ' Size destination array
    ReDim Dst(0 To EmployeeCount * DateCount, 1 To 4)

    ' Headers
    Dst(0, 1) = "Employee Name"
    Dst(0, 2) = "Date"
    Dst(0, 3) = "Time In"
    Dst(0, 4) = "Time Out"

    ' Loop source data, process each Time In row
    DstRow = 0
    For SrcRow = 1 To UBound(Src, 1)
        If StrComp(Src(SrcRow, 2), "Time In", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' Loop dates for each employee
            For DateRow = 1 To DateCount
                Dst(DateRow + DstRow, 1) = Src(SrcRow, 1) 'Name
                Dst(DateRow + DstRow, 2) = Src(1, DateRow + 2) 'Date
                If Not IsEmpty(Src(SrcRow, DateRow + 2)) Then
                    Dst(DateRow + DstRow, 3) = Src(SrcRow, DateRow + 2) ' In
                    Dst(DateRow + DstRow + 1, 4) = Src(SrcRow + 1, DateRow + 2) ' Out
                End If
            Next
            DstRow = DstRow + DateCount
        End If
    Next

    ' Place result on sheet
    Set rDst = wsDst.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Dst, 1) + 1, UBound(Dst, 2))
    rDst.Value = Dst

    ' Format Date and Time Columns
    rDst.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    rDst.Columns(3).Resize(, 2).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"

Exit Sub
EH:
    ' on error restore source data
    If Not IsEmpty(Src) Then
        wsSrc.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Src, 1), UBound(Src, 2)).Value = Src
    End If
    MsgBox "Oops..."
End Sub
```

Since you have many sheets to process, you'll need another `Sub` to process those, and call this `Sub`

Demo of calling for one sheet

```
Sub Demo()
    TransposeTime ActiveSheet
End Sub
```